# ng-if and check for a non-empty, non-null object

Tags: angularjs, select, angular-ng-if

I'm trying this:

```
<select ng-disabled="!items" class="form-control" ng-model="selected" ng-options="key as value for (key , value) in items">
    <option ng-if="items" value="">All Items</option>
</select>
```

But `All Items` option doesn't show up when there are items.

**Note:** The problem is due to `ng-if`, nothing else.

***DEMO:*** http://plnkr.co/edit/jarknWGYXiHdGIWNtMvC?p=preview

Comment: instead of `ng-options` you could have an `ng-repeat` on an `<option>`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I know that but this question is about `ng-if` alternatives or a way to fix this issue without using `ng-repeat` instead of `ng-options`. Thanks!

Comment: Alternatively, just add that dummy options of yours to `items` array

Comment: You can use `ng-show` as an alternative to `ng-if`

Comment: What do you mean, "`ng-if` alternative"? This makes it an ["XY question"](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: items always exists. Try items.length < 1 or == null

Comment: @Tushar, i tried `ng-hide="!items"` but it doesn't hide that `option` -.-'

Comment: @Billy, i already tried that but isn't working.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev So to you a possible solution also could be stop using AngularJS and use other framework. Lol

Comment: @Christopher what exactly you want to your code do? Do you want to show `All Items` when `items` is empty, or when it's not empty?

Comment: @Christopher: my apologies, I was a bit rude :)

Comment: @rzysia I want to show `All Items` when `items` isn't empty. PS: `ng-disabled` is working with the above code.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, np xD

Comment: @Christopher: I took the liberty to rephrase the question title. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Include a link to plunker, btw. So people can see the code in action.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yep, thanks!

Comment: It seems that angular just *ignores* the ng-if/ng-show/ng-hide here (and, probably, most other stuff). Interpolation works, though. Not sure if bug or feature. I'd create a bug report for angular.

Answer (score 4):

You can check if the object id empty like this

```
$scope.isEmpty = function (obj) {
for (var i in obj) if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) return false;
return true;
};
```

and in the view you can do:

```
 <option ng-show="!isEmpty(items)">All Items</option>
```

ng-if is not working here in the option tag -- This would happen because the select element is higher up the DOM tree than the null option with the ng-if, so it would compile first.
[see the angular source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/11f5aeeee952a395edaf54e3277674f211a82fc7/src/ng/directive/select.js#L236)

Comment: I feel that there should be a function for this in angular or jquery. Isn't there one?

Comment: In angular there is angular.equals({}, $scope.items) perhaps

Answer (score 0):

This has been a good option for me:

```js
angular
  .module('myApp')
  .filter('empty', function() {
    return function(obj) {
      return obj === null || angular.equals({}, obj)
    }
  })
```

```html
<span ng-if="items|empty">0 items</span>
```

Adding the function as a filter and using Angular to test.

Thanks to @Hmahwish for the inspiration.